# Is using "short of something" to express "missing/lacking something" grammatical?

Tags: expressions, prepositions, american-english, british-english

I have heard two conflicting opinions on the following:

> They want to play football but they are short of one man.

The intended meaning was that they were missing one player.

Now, a colleague from the US told that this is not grammatical and should really be "they are one player short" or "short by one player".
On the hand, a friend of mine from England finds that perfectly normal and correct.

Comment: To be 'short of' something is perfectly idiomatic in British English.

Comment: @KateBunting I know it is idiomatic in the sense of "not having enough of something" (I am short of money), but can you say "I am short of 5 poinds", meaning I am lacking 5 pounds?

Comment: _Short_ is a metaphor, and not a synonym. We have a lot of ways to refer to lack. _He lacks a finger/is missing a finger/doesn't have a finger/has lost a finger/is short a finger_. They are not synonyms, however; some are ambiguous, others are not, some have presuppositions, others don't. Oh, and since they're negatives, they tend to be idiomatic, and have their own grammar. I woudn't say, for instance, *_He is short of a finger_.

Comment: @JohnLawler But I would!

Comment: Consider “a day late and a dollar short.”

Comment: More idiomatic in the US would be "short one man".

Comment: @KateBunting We do use it without the 'of' as well, though. Remember Ken Dodd's catch phrase "Wheers me shert? I'm shert short!"

Comment: "Down one man" for comparison without "of" in AmE.  When short-staffed, the shorthand is often just "short," as in, "We're short two people."  No Randy Newman references.